# Android HTML5 Application and Next Button on input

Tags: android, html, angularjs

I got application written on html5. I got the code:

```
<input id="hour" type="number" min="0" max="23" required />
<p>:</p>
<input id="minute" type="number" min="0" max="59" required />
```

After i touch input on the screen i got virtual keyboard. There is "Go" button. If i think correct, this is possible to change that button to the "next" button, which can be used to move focus from hour input to the minute input after pressing. I cannot get the next button, how to get that?

Comment: pls post a little more of your code - I didn't understand your problem

Comment: Edited (Sry for my english)